# Meteor HTTP and Twitter API call Auth

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to make calls using -

```
HTTP.call("GET", sUrl, oAuth)
```

Where sUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi" or something similar (making the query dynamic, etc) and oAuth is where I need help in constructing.

What I would like to know is how do I authenticate on via the Twitter API using Meteor's HTTP.call.

Appreciate any help.

Greg.

Comment: this might be useful it's twitter api with meteor's HTTP package https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-twitter-api/blob/master/lib/twitter.js

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to build the functionality up myself though. And understand how to use the HTTP.call functionality to it's full capability.

Comment: @lionysis can you point to documentation on Twitter authentication? We can help you set up your HTTP call if we know the format

Comment: Hi FullStack - 
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search - I will be using this primarily.
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests - this is the auth documentation which I just can't seem to make much sense of in the HTTP.call method - I'm just not sure how to construct it.

Comment: Note: when generating an OAuth Signature for a particular app - this is the CURL option. If I could convert the CURL option to HTTP it would be ideal.


 curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' --data 'q=STRING_TO_QUERY' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MY_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_nonce="91b9e0d4b7e18d234c8be586708222e7", oauth_signature="Z3mhCS9QsNhRar0Zg1chRPb0N2U%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1439338299", oauth_token="GENERATED_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"'

Any help on this part?